# OPC sample application for C#

Tags: c#, .net, opc

Does anyone know a C# OPC client sample application? I'm looking for a good opensource one to learn about the protocol. I would prefer it if it uses OPC foundation .net core apis.

Comment: Are you looking for the old COM based OPC, or OPC UA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://fistfulofbytes.com/opc-sample-code
I have posted sample code on how to use a dll "Interop.OPCAutomation.dll" enjoy...

Answer (score 5):

YOu may like this to visit
http://www.opcconnect.com/source.php

Comment: Sorry dude no .net sample there... no free ones anyways

Answer (score 4):

Visit the following webpages, where you can find source code, project files and documentation:

- [Individual Visualization with OPC based on Microsoft® .NET and the Programming Language C#](http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&lang=en&objid=21043779&caller=view)
- [Mass Data Acquisition with an OPC Client in C# based on .NET](http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&lang=en&objid=21447513&caller=view)

Comment: thanks... but i ran into some problems with those... i posted simpler code if you want to check it out

Answer (score 2):

For the newer OPC UA specification, you can try the [OPC UA Services for WPF](https://opcuaservicesforwpf.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

Comment: unfortunately that link is dead

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET project named 'My OPC Client' here:
http://hadiscada.blogspot.com/2013/07/my-opc-client.html
it coded with VB but I think it can be converted to C.